# What the methods do which starts with getXXXX()?

Tags: java, methods, return

I have to use these two methods in my program but I have no idea what they do because my program works the way I want it to without these and when I put them in my code it doesn't make a difference in the output or anything.

```
 public double getPurchase() {
    return purchase;
}

public int getItems() {
    return numItems;
}
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
public class GroceryListIU extends javax.swing.JFrame {

NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
public double itemPrice;
public final double SALES_TAX = 0.065;
public double totalPrice;
public double tax;
public double purchase;
public int numItems;

/**
 * Creates new form GroceryListIU
 */
public GroceryListIU() {
    initComponents();
    //delcares purchase and numItems and resets them to 0
    purchase = 0;
    numItems = 0;
}
//set method to add item price
public void recordPurchase(double itemPrice) {
    purchase = purchase + itemPrice;
    numItems++;
}

public double getPurchase() {
    return purchase;
}

public int getItems() {
    return numItems;
}

private void btnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    //clicking exit ends the program
    System.exit(0);
}                                       

private void btnResetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //When the user clicks "reset" all variables are set to blank or 0
    txtItemPrice.setText("");
    txtSubTotal.setText("");
    txtNumberOfItems.setText("");
    txtSalesTax.setText("");
    txtTotalPrice.setText("");
    numItems = 0;
    purchase = 0;
}                                        

private void btnCheckoutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    boolean keepShopping = true;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    while (keepShopping) {
        try {
            //When the user clicks "checkout" a input dialog will appear to enter the item price
            String newItemPrice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                    "Enter Item Price",
                    "Enter Price",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            //if the user clicks cancel or clicks OK and left the text field blank, calculations will be made
            if ((newItemPrice != null) && (newItemPrice.length() > 0)) {

                //parse the double item price
                itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(newItemPrice);

                //takes itemPrice and plugs it into recordPurchase method
                recordPurchase(itemPrice);

                //adds 1 to txtNumberOfItems each time the user enters a number until it ends
                txtNumberOfItems.setText((numItems) + "");

                //adds item price to the txtItemPrice text field
                txtItemPrice.setText(defaultFormat.format(itemPrice));

                //adds the sub total to the txtSubTotal text field
                txtSubTotal.setText(defaultFormat.format(purchase));

            } else {
                //when the user clicks ok when blank or cancel the program does the rest of the calculations
                keepShopping = false;

                //tax is 6.5%, you would multiply that by the purchase total
                tax = SALES_TAX * purchase;

                //sets "tax" in the txtSalesTax text field
                txtSalesTax.setText(defaultFormat.format(tax));

                //the total price is tax plus the sub total
                totalPrice = tax + purchase;

                //add the total price to the totalPrice text field
                txtTotalPrice.setText(defaultFormat.format(totalPrice));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { //if the user enters string data, an error will appear
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                    "You must enter positive numerical data!",
                    "Bad Data!",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I use them in my program?

Comment: Let's say I put a plate on the table, and then I never think about it or use it. Is there a problem?

Comment: I'm asking how do I use them inn my program

Comment: I don't like at all this kind of questions : the guy comes here and hasn't searched at all, seems having absolutely no skills about programming, askes a silly question and that's OK. Someone answers, gets 5 upvotes and everybody is happy. And finally, this will never be useful no anyone else. Thanks to you OP.

Comment: This question is about basic bread and butter Java that is explained fully in the first 2 chapters of any Java text book. This question suggests that you haven't yet started studying. Please understand that you can't get a foundation in the basics from this site, but only from diligent study. This is what you need to do now.

Comment: @OlivierH Does your question always interesting/useful for many people?

Comment: @MarounMaroun This is the main goal of SO. Not a race to got some points and medals. But as I said no problem, everybody is happy. Good job !

Comment: @OlivierH As I told you in my comment to my answer, I don't know what about you.. **I'm not here for points**. Don't, just don't do shallow assumptions here.

Comment: While the question is weak, @MarounMaroun's answer is a good one. The up-votes are to indicate that to the OP and future user's of the site.

Answer (score 4):

Therese are [*getters*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html). You might have them on your program, but you never used them.

Note that they are `public`, while the variables they return should have been `private`. You're breaking [*encapsulation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) by exposing your data members.

Consider this class:

```
public class MyClass {
   private int    myPrivateInt;
   private String myPrivateString;

   public int getInt() {
       return myPrivateInt;
   }

   public String getString() {
       return myPrivateString;
   }
}
```

Since `myPricateInt` and `myPrivateString` are `private`, you can't access them from outside, that's why I need a *getter* method to get these variables.

Answer (score 1):

They are **getters**

The point of **getters** and **setters** is that only they are meant to be used to access the private varialble, which they are getting or setting. This way you provide encapsulation and it will be much easier to refactor or modify your code later.

Short and sweet advantages are

1. For Re-usability.
2. To perform Validation in later stages of programming.
3. Getter and setter methods are public interfaces to access private
   class members

As per ur Q

```
public double getPurchase() {
    return purchase;
}

public int getItems() {
    return numItems;
}
```

`purchase` and `numItems` are private, so u need getters

Answer (score 0):

This is `encapsulation`.

If you have getters like these, then `private` access modifiers on your fields would make them more meaningful.

```
private double purchase;
private int numItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly Question. 
Those are getter methods for the variables purchase and nemItems, which are private . 
Accessors and Mutators in Java. Does it ring a bell.

Answer (score 0):

They are set and get methods. `Public double getPurchase()` returns the `purchase` variable from the class and `public int getItems()` returns the `numItems` variable. The reason it doesn't affect your code when you remove them is because you are accessing those variables directly because they are public. You would have to use those methods if you had your variables set to private.